# Understanding Ruby-code presented in book Practical Object Oriented Design

Tags: ruby

I'm currently reading the book called `Practical Object Oriented Design in Ruby`. I'm new to Ruby and I know that understanding the code presented in the book is not required as long as you understand the concepts, which I do but a piece of code that I found in chapter 2 is bothering me a bit.

In chapter 2 the author shows the following Ruby class...

```
class Gear  
    attr_reader :chainring, :cog  
    def initialize(chainring, cog)  
        @chainring = chainring 
        @cog       = cog  6    
    end  

     def ratio  
        chainring / cog.to_f 
    end 
end 

puts Gear.new(52, 11).ratio        
puts Gear.new(30, 27).ratio
```

The part that I don't know understand is that she say this class contains three methods, `chainring`,`cog` and `ratio` but I only see one method (`ratio`) and two symbols (`chainring` and `cog`).

Can someone verify the code above and tell me if this is a mistake of the author or in fact there are three methods?

Quote from the book:

> Each instance implements three methods:`chainring`,`cog` and `ratio`.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two methods (`chainring` and `cog`) are implicitly defined by [`attr_reader`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Module.html#method-i-attr_reader):

```
attr_reader :chainring, :cog
```

Comment: Thank you for the clearification. I thought `:chainring` and `:cog` were symbols, I read somewhere that you define symbols by using the colon "`:`". I'm not familiar with symbols either anyways. Thanks

Comment: @fs_tigre The `:chainring` is a symbol. It's also a parameter of the method [`attr_reader()`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Module.html#method-i-attr_reader). This method creates simple getter methods.

Comment: @sschmeck Hmm, I need to read more about this whole concept of symbols and accessor/readers. Thanks

Comment: fs, you could also write `attr_reader "chainring", :cog`. Many (most? all?) of Ruby's methods ([Module#attr_accessor](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Module.html#method-i-attr_accessor) being one) allow an argument to be either a symbol or a string when it represents a method. (Why not?)

Answer (score 4):

The methods are created with the `attr_reader` macro. You can show all methods in your example with `instance_methods`.

```
p Gear.instance_methods(false)
#=> [:chainring, :cog, :ratio]
```

Comment: `attr_reader` is by no mean “a macro.” It is plain old good method, defined on `Module` class.

Comment: @mudasobwa I call it macro because of its usage. It doesn't matter where it's defined. How do you define macro in the Ruby world?

Comment: I won’t. This question is similar to “how would you define ‘leaf’ in pine-trees world.” :)

Comment: BTW I've taken my definition from [_Metaprogramming Ruby_](https://pragprog.com/book/ppmetr/metaprogramming-ruby).

Comment: There's an analogy here with the use of the term "operator" to describe what is in fact a method. Nevertheless, I must side with @mudasobwa, because "operator" is part of the official Ruby documentation (but never defined?) and is sprinkled throughout every book on Ruby. By contrast, I don't recall seeing "macro" in any of those places (including *Metaprogramming Ruby*, though I don't question that it's there). Also, the term may be confusing those new to Ruby who are familiar to C-type macros. Lastly, by using the term "method" you are educating readers who do not realize that's what it is.

Comment: @CarySwoveland yes, I beware of those newbies who would treat the term “macro” as having _anything_ in common with `C`-type macros. It is a challenge to meet a really object oriented language and to accept it’s paradigms. On the other hand, Elixir evolved “macro” term and even made it acceptable :) So, I am uncertain whether I love “macro” term, or not, but anyway “you are educating readers who do not realize that's what it is.” Thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 2):

```
attr_reader :chainring, :cog
```

is equivalent to

```
def chainring
  @chainring
end

def cog
  @cog
end
```

Writing methods like these by hand is boring, so ruby provides a shortcut.